# Check Point Endpoint Security VPN works with litte setup, other clients do not

Tags: vpn, checkpoint-endpoint

I am connecting with Check Point Endpoint Security VPN to my companies VPN.
The client was NOT preinstalled or preconfigured. I just installed it, clicked "New" put in the server address "vpn.company.com" and connected using username and password.

This just worked which is good since I have no information about the VPN and nobody seems to know more.

Now I want to connect with a different client. Either FortiClient or the integrated MacOS client.
But there is so much to configure and I cannot get it to work.

How does Check Point do all that?
Can I somehow see the configuration?

I can chose between L2TP over IPSec, Isco IPSec and KEv2 in the Mac client and SSL VPN or IPSec in FortiClient.

After that there is a multitude of additional settings.
But I don't have a certificate or a shared key.

Does anybody have an idea how this works and how to setup the clients?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation specifies that the settings are stored in the
[TRAC File](https://theworldsgonemad.net/2019/checkpoint-vpn/#trac-file),
stored in `C:\Program Files\CheckPoint\Endpoint Connect`.

By default the file is encrypted. To view or edit, you need to first
open the `trac.defaults` file and on the first Line change the value of `OBSCURE_FILE INT` from `1` to `0`.
The Checkpoint Endpoint Security VPN service must be restarted for this
to take effect.

Comment: Ok that worked so far, thank you
I got <PARAM conn_type="IPSec"></PARAM> so that is a first step.

There seems to be a certificate in the ica_cert_object section.
I tried to import this as described here https://github.com/schlatterbeck/snxvpn/issues/7#issuecomment-317699197 with the "BEGIN" and "END". But it cannot be imported.

The installed certificates the client shows for usage don't work either

I guess that can be the only thing that's missing.